# Re-ordering a Silverlight Listbox - MVVM-stylee

Tags: silverlight, mvvm, listbox

I am using RIA services to serve entities to a MVVM-Light enabled Silverlight application.

I have a ViewModel which present a CollectionViewSource of entities to a listbox on the View.  The reason I use a CollectionViewSource is so I can control the selected item in the ViewModel; when a new item is created I can create it and then select it for further editing (selecting an item in the listbox enables the editing of that item in a data form).

I need to enable dragdropping for the listbox to allow reordering of the items.  I have looked at using the Silverlight Toolkit's ListBoxDragDropTarget to enable this functionality but it doesn't work - I assume this is because I need to set the listbox ItemsSource to an ObservableCollection.

If I change the CollectionViewSource in the ViewModel to an ObservableCollection how can I programmatically change the Selected Item of the listbox from the ViewModel?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can wrap your `ObservableCollection<T>` within the `CollectionViewSource`...as seen [here](http://www.silverlightplayground.org/post/2009/07/10/Silverlight-30-RTW-The-CollectionViewSource.aspx)...so that it is the backing collection of data used by the `CollectionViewSource` gaining the `INotifyCollectionChanged` behavior without losing the benefits from the `CollectionViewSource`; which you need for selecting an item.

```
    <UserControl.Resources>
       <local:DataSource x:Key="dataSource" />
          <CollectionViewSource x:Name="cvs" 
                    Source="{Binding Names, Source={StaticResource dataSource}}">
          </CollectionViewSource>
    </UserControl.Resources>

    ...

    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource cvs}}" 
               Margin="5,5,5,1" Grid.ColumnSpan="4" />
```

An end to end example from Tim Heuer can be found [here](http://timheuer.com/blog/archive/2009/10/19/silverlight-toolkit-adds-drag-drop-support.aspx) which should also help you out in achieving the complete solution.

Comment: Actually turns out I can't get either approaches suggested here to work with MVVM pattern, looks like it might be a bug with the ListBoxDragDropTarget...

Comment: @Drammy Check this out...http://silverlightfeeds.com/post/1325/Silverlight_Toolkit_adds_DragDrop_targets.aspx as it has an end to end example...

Comment: Thanks Aaron, working through this helped me crack it!  My Listbox was just a regular ListBox, however the one in the example posted uses a StackPanel as the ItemsPanelTemplate...  It probably says this in the manual somewhere as well!  RTFM!  :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can have a separate property in your ViewModel namely `SelectedThing` and bind `ListBox.SelectedItem` to it

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding TheCollection}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedThing}" />
```

Comment: Thanks alpha-mouse - I actually tried this approach already but I must have done something wrong as I didn't get it working how I wanted. If I was starting afresh then I would go with this route. But the suggestion by Aaron means less work... (is that just being lazy?)